# css grid-template-areas property not aligning grid items

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

I am new to css grids, and I am trying to build a page with this layout:

[image]

The problem I have is the `.main` class and the grid inside the container grid.

I think I have the wrong setup for the grid in `.main`.

For the upper container `.container`, I can see that three columns layout is working.

[image]

On the first row, I want the div image div to span 2 out of three columns, and blogart div to take up one column.

The second row should have three blogart divs spaning one column each.

But in the inner grid `.main`, all the markup is in a fourth column.

[image]

I have setup a [codepen](https://codepen.io/lupis/pen/BRoobQ?editors=1100#0) Greatful for any suggestions.

This is my markup, the css is in the codepen:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: #f5f7f8;
}

.container{
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 80px 180px 80px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  
  grid-template-areas: "header   header   header"
                       "main     main     main"
                       "footer   footer   footer";
}

.container div{
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.header {
  background: #b03532;
  grid-area: header;
}

.main {
  background: #33a8a5;
  grid-area: main;
  
  display: grid;
  
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  
  grid-template-areas: "bigimg bigimg blogart"
                       "blogart blogart blogart";
  
}

.bigimg {
  background: #da6f2b;
  grid-area: bigimg;
}

.blogart {
  background: #3d8bb1;
  grid-area: blogart;
}

.footer {
  background: #6a478f;
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="bigimg">img</div>
    <div class="blogart">blogart</div>
    <div class="blogart">blogart</div>
    <div class="blogart">blogart</div>
    <div class="blogart">blogart</div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</section>
```

-Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to name multiple grid areas “blogart”, but this is invalid. You cannot name multiple grid areas with the same name.

There are several ways to define a grid, apart from using named template areas. Instead of using `grid-template-areas` in your inner grid, you might want to rely on the grid auto-placement algorithm.

Try something like this:

```
.main {
  background: #33a8a5;
  grid-area: main;

  display: grid;

  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

Then, each grid item in the grid will automatically lay out, one per grid cell, for three columns, until they have all been placed.

---

*edit*

Here’s a more complete demo: https://codepen.io/keithjgrant/pen/JNGNKX

I made a few changes:

- I removed the `grid-template-rows` from the outer grid. You had constrained the heights of each row; it's better to allow the contents to grow/shrink automatically as necessary.
- I removed the `grid-template-areas` from the inner grid and the `grid-area` from its grid items. This allows them to lay out naturally, in the order they appear. Each grid item will fill one grid cell by default.
- I added a `grid-column: span 2` to the img, since you want that to span 2 columns.

Play around with that. Notice you can now add (or remove) as many “blogart” elements you want, and the layout still works.

Comment: i saw my error with multiple blogart areas. But with the .blogart:nth-child(3) spanning between column 1-3, do we need  a markup with 4 blogart elements?
Is'nt sufficient with 2 blogart elements in my markup?

Comment: Edited to add a link to a more complete demo

Comment: I’m not exactly sure what you mean about it being “sufficient with 2 blogart elements”...? The point is, if you define the grid in a flexible way, you can have as many (or as few) elements in the markup as you want, and the layout still works.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is this section of your code:

```
.main {
  grid-template-areas: "bigimg  bigimg  blogart"
                       "blogart blogart blogart";
}
```

The layout is invalid.

*From the spec:*

> [**7.3. Named Areas: the `grid-template-areas`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-template-areas-property)
>
> This property specifies ***named grid areas***, which are not
>   associated with any particular grid item, but can be referenced from
>   the grid-placement properties.
>
> The syntax of the `grid-template-areas` property also provides a
>   visualization of the structure of the grid, making the overall layout
>   of the grid container easier to understand.
>
> *All strings must have the same number of columns, or else the declaration is invalid.*
>
> ***If a named grid area spans multiple grid cells, but those cells do not form a single filled-in rectangle, the declaration is invalid.***
>
> *Note: Non-rectangular or disconnected regions may be permitted in a future version of this module.*
>
> <sup>*(emphasis mine)*</sup>

In short, your `.blogart` visualization is L-shaped, not rectangular, so it doesn't work.

This is not a problem with your `.container` visualization, which works fine:

```
.container {
  grid-template-areas: "header   header   header"
                       "main     main     main"
                       "footer   footer   footer";
}
```

To make your layout work consider using `grid-column` and `grid-row` on the grid items. Here's a rough sketch, based on your demo:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: #f5f7f8;
}
.container{
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 80px 180px 80px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-areas: "header   header   header"
                       "main     main     main"
                       "footer   footer   footer";
}
.container div {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.header {
  background: #b03532;
  grid-area: header;
}
.main {
  background: #33a8a5;
  grid-area: main;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  /* grid-template-areas: "bigimg bigimg blogart"
                       "blogart blogart blogart"; */
  
}
.bigimg {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background: #da6f2b;
  /* grid-area: bigimg; */
}
.blogart:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  background: #3d8bb1;
  /* grid-area: blogart; */
}
.blogart:not(:nth-child(2)) {
  grid-column: auto / span 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: orange;
  /* grid-area: blogart; */
}

.footer {
  background: #6a478f;
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="bigimg">img</div>
    <div class="blogart">blogart</div>
    <div class="blogart">blogart</div>
    <div class="blogart">blogart</div>
    <div class="blogart">blogart</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</section>
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybYGNK?editors=1100)

Comment: thanks for all the help :)